# How to include a "build policy" step in Azure B2C GitHub Action for custom policy deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am currently working on setting up a GitHub Action for the automatic deployment of my Azure B2C Custom Policies.
I am following the instructions
Microsoft Learn documentation: Deploy custom policies with GitHub Actions - Azure AD B2C.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/deploy-custom-policies-github-action

While going through the documentation, I noticed that the Action deploys the policies directly from my GitHub repository.

However, I would like to add a step in the workflow that builds the policy using the **appsettings.json** file before uploading it to the repository. This way, I don't have to manually build the policy and then upload it to the repository.

want to know how to include the "build policy" step in the GitHub Action workflow mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: it's unclear what you mean by "build policy". if you got some local script to replace variables or whatever, then just add this to your pipeline.